# Why does 'export foo=1' not get read when I use ssh?

Tags: linux, ssh, environment-variables

I'm trying to set a remote environment variable explicitly in an ssh command:

```
ssh worker-2 "export OPENBLAS_NUM_THREADS=1; echo $OPENBLAS_NUM_THREADS"
```

Strangely, this prints just a blank line, but when I run the same command locally, it correctly prints `1`.

Since I'm setting the variable explicitly, why isn't it working remotely?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$OPENBLAS_NUM_THREADS` is being evaluated locally by `bash` before it is sent to your remote machine.

You need to either escape the `$`:

```
ssh worker-2 "export OPENBLAS_NUM_THREADS=1; echo \$OPENBLAS_NUM_THREADS"
```

or use single quotes, which inhibit the bash variable evaluation:

```
ssh worker-2 'export OPENBLAS_NUM_THREADS=1; echo $OPENBLAS_NUM_THREADS'
```